# How to use two strings in a layout?

Tags: android

I try to make a simple app and I used two strings in strings.xml:

```
<string name="question">is the capital of:</string>
<string name="riga">Riga</string>
```

And I want to add them to one text view.

I want the output to be (Riga is the capital of: ).

How can I do this?

This is my layout:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/riga" + "@string/question"
    />
```

Comment: No, you can't do it like that, you can add the two Strings and `setText()` programmatically though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this in XML. You could do it in Java, however. Assuming you're inside an `Activity`:

```
String riga = getString(R.string.riga);
String question = getString(R.string.question);

TextView tv = findViewById(/* your id here */);
tv.setText(riga + question);
```

Even better would be to use *format arguments* in one of your strings:

```
<string name="question">%1$s is the capital of:</string>
```

And then do this in your activity:

```
String riga = getString(R.string.riga);
String fullQuestion = getString(R.string.question, riga);

TextView tv = findViewById(/* your id here */);
tv.setText(fullQuestion);
```